# PHP Call a function from a hyperlink

Tags: php

I have a list of file download urls that will be displayed to user and upon user clicking it will trigger download. I am using the following code:

```
echo "<a href=$val1 download=\"$fileId.$fileformat\".>Click Here To Download</a>";
```

But how do I change this so that a function is called instead of download as I need to do some processing before download. I used the following but it is not working:

```
echo "<a href=$val1 onclick=func($val1,$fileId,$fileformat)>Click Here To Download</a>";
```

Is there any other way to call a function from hyperlink?

I tried using if(isset($_GET['id'])) way but I have a list of links which I need to display to user and when user clicks one than pass to function to trigger download.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX to call a PHP function from an anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a php function directly from html.

The solution for your problem is to call a php file that will run the function and return file for download

Ex.

```
<a href="download-file.php?val1=$val1&fileId=$fileId&fileFormat=$fileFormat">Click Here To Download</a>
```

your donwload-file.php file check and validate the $_GET and you will run the function you need to return the result.

Comment: My $val1 is a url and contains "&" characters, so when I do the $_GET['val1'], I couldn't get the full url, it get cuts off at the first "&" . Any idea, how do I resolve it? The other parameters has no issue.

Comment: There is different ways how to fix this: - use urlencode($val1) to encode the link OR - instead of sending the url in $val1 send an integer and in your dwonload-file.php you will use a switch statement to get the url string OR use explode() to $url to a smaller parts and pass it as other var.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "<a href='javascript:;' onclick=func('".$val1."','".$fileId."','".$fileformat."')>
   Click Here To Download</a>";
```

Comment: I tried your code, but when i click on the link, it goes to the link itself and is not triggering the function. Any idea where I am wrong?

Comment: @aandroidtest test the above I have made changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link_id").click(function() {
//Your code here
});


echo "<a href=$val1 download=\"$fileId.$fileformat\". id='link_id'>Click Here To Download</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to start a php function "onclick" is using $_GET[].

There are two ways for you to do this:

1. You href a variable, eg. the trigger.

   ```
   <a href="?variable=value">click</a>
   <?php
   if(isset($_GET['variable'])) {
      $variable = $_GET['variable'];

      /* now you can either directly execute your
         function, create a switch or an if/elseif block */

      switch($variable) {
         case "file1":
            function myFunction() {
            /* your function */
            }
         break 1;
      }
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. you create a class (OOP) and include it in your file:

   ```
   <?php
   $trigger = $_GET['trigger'];
   include "include_path/class_name.php";
   ?>
   ```

class:

```
    <?php
    class ClassName {

      function ClassName() {
      global $trigger;

        if($trigger == "value1") {
        // your function
        }

        if($trigger == "value2") {
        $this->myFunction();
        }

        if($trigger == "value3") {
        $otherClassName->myOtherFunction();
        }

      }

    }
    ?>
```